# Microsoft graph batch inserting new task and updating details

Tags: odata, microsoft-graph-api

Current steps for creating task are

`POST /planner/tasks`

`GET /planner/tasks/{id from post call}/details`

```
PATCH /planner/tasks/{id from post call}/details
If-Match: {etag from get call}
```

but I want to batch three steps in single call using https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/json_batching

And according to odata v4 references http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.01/csprd02/odata-json-format-v4.01-csprd02.html#sec_ReferencingNewEntities  we can refer entities in same batch call using `${id of other request}`

```
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "id": "task",
            "url": "/planner/tasks",
            "body": {
                "title": "asff",
                "appliedCategories": {
                    "category5": true
                },
                "planId": "mSV7ODf3g0iTJrUtsNcvHZYAB-ZW",
                "bucketId": "WFN6kxMykE-4xxqLUh1uS5YALCWq",
                "assignments": {
                    "4393baf8-8a52-4164-bf93-b1cba5130329": {
                        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.plannerAssignment",
                        "orderHint": " !"
                    }
                },
                "dueDateTime": "2018-04-23T18:30:00.000Z"
            },
            "method": "POST",
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "getDetail",
            "method": "GET",
            "dependsOn": [
                "task"
            ],
            "url": "/planner/tasks/$task/details"
        },
        {
            "id": "patchDetail",
            "dependsOn": [
                "getDetail"
            ],
            "url": "/planner/tasks/$task/details",
            "method": "PATCH",
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "if-match": "$getDetail"
            },
            "body": {
                "description": "gwrthbetrhnety"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

but Get details call is failing with error

```
{
    "id": "getDetail",
    "status": 400,
    "body": {
        "error": {
            "code": "BadRequest",
            "message": "The request URI is not valid. Since the segment 'tasks' refers to a collection, this must be the last segment in the request URI or it must be followed by an function or action that can be bound to it otherwise all intermediate segments must refer to a single resource.",
            "innerError": {
                "request-id": "a46ce528-993f-4cff-865e-98b2b98d5f23",
                "date": "2018-04-17T10:38:29"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong here

Comment: Did you ever get any answer, I'm in the same boat trying to figure this ODATA out in 2021 :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what is missing is the URI (should be POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch instead of POST /planner/tasks) and "id" field has to be numeric. Check out MS documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0

[Here is an example of combining POST and GET in a batch call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfsMs.png)